# Split them with spaces as delimiter, but the spaces in <> should be ignored in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I'd like to split them with spaces as delimiter, but the spaces in <> should be ignored.

The output to `"abc <def deaf;hello world> good"` should be

- abc
- `<def deaf;hello world>`
- good

How can I implement this in Java?
RegEx should work, but implementing without regEx would be better.

Comment: Why don't you want a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to walk the string:

```
ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
int i, last = 0;
int depth = 0;
for(i=0; i != string.length(); ++i) {
    if(string.charAt(i) == '<') ++depth;
    else if(string.charAt(i) == '>') { if(depth >0) --depth; }
    else if(string.charAt(i) == ' ' && depth == 0) {
        out.add(string.substring(last, i));
        last = i+1;
    }
}
if(last < string.length()) out.add(string.substring(last));
```

for your sample `"abc <def deaf;hello world> good"`, the result is `["abc", "<def deaf;hello world>", "good"]`